# Can not connect to wireless printer in windows 7

Tags: printing, wireless-networking

I have a windows 7 computer and when I go to "Devices and Printers" then I click add printer, then i pick add a network wireless printer. But it searches and searches and never finds the wireless printer to connect to. Its an HP officejet 6500, any help is welcomes!

Thanks!

Comment: Has it been configured at least once via the usb plugged in?

Comment: See this article...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Connect-to-Bluetooth-and-other-wireless-or-network-devices

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once before. My solution was to use the drivers disk. The drivers disk comes with a utility that will configure the printer to work wireless if wasn't configured already or it would find the wireless printer, install the drivers, and configure it for use. <strike>If you do not have the driver then search HP's site for them.</strike> Here is the [official drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3795406&).

*Will update answer if more information is provide.*